# Airflow Dag run goes into queue

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x, airflow-api

facing the a issue when i run the Airflow DAG by using the `api`. 2nd run goes into queue. after first run only its starting. ideally we want to run in parallel. same rest `api` call is working in Airflow 2.2.2 but in 2.7.3 its queuing.
also

```
max_active_runs is 10
```

```
with DAG('DAG-21',schedule_interval=None,start_date=datetime(2022,10,5),max_active_runs=10) as dag:
```

how can we run the parallel dag runs in airflow 2.7.3

Comment: You need to add the schedule_interval. Otherwise, the DAG will only run if triggered.

The first DAG Run is created based on the minimum start_date for the tasks in your DAG. Subsequent DAG Runs are created by the scheduler process, based on your DAG’s schedule_interval, sequentially.

Comment: I recommend checking your scheduler logs to see why task instances for this DAG aren't getting queued.